# Вывести все значения ключей обьекта и вложенных в том числе

Tags: javascript

Есть JS обьект в котором еще есть вложенные обьекты. Не могу придумать как вывести в консоль абсолютно все значения.

```
let man = {
    name : "David",
    surname: "Ray",
    sizes: {
        height: 189,
        width: 60
    },
    age: 25
};
// David, Ray, 189, 60, 25
```

Comment: Рекурсией, очевидно. Непонятно только зачем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу любить и жаловать

```js
let man = {
  name: "David",
  surname: "Ray",
  sizes: {
    height: 189,
    width: 60,
    double: {
      test: "test"
    }
  },
  age: 25
};

let result = "";

function getValue(val) {
  // Создаём времменый массив с данными
  let array = Object.values(val);
  // Обрабатываем каждый элемент массива
  for (elem of array) {
    // Если элемент массива объект то вызываем данную функцию с текущем объектом
    // Используем continue что-бы не обратывать одни и те же данные 2 раза, можно испоользовать else
    if (typeof elem === 'object') {
      getValue(elem);
      continue;
    }
    result += ' ' + elem;
  }
}

getValue(man)
console.log(result);
```